# Do I need to use "and" to add indirect details

Tags: grammar, prepositions, sentence-construction

I would like to add some information to my sentence, indirectly. So, I wonder, do I need to use **and** or not.

> In this research, and instead of doing A as in reference B, we will investigate...

or

> In this research, instead of doing A as in reference B, we will investigate...

Similarly,

> In this research, and through its sections, we will illustrate...

or

> In this research, through its sections, we will illustrate....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first two examples, you definitely do NOT need **and**.

What you are saying in effect is:

> In this research, instead of doing this, we will do that.

Your second pair of examples differs in meaning.

The first of them is saying that both in the research (generally) AND through its sections (in particular) you will do whatever.

The second is saying that it is through the sections of the research that you will do whatever. The sections are the means by which you will illustrate your results.

Comment: Thank you so, so much for your help. This type of answer helps me to not only understand my case but also helps me to understand how my word changes the meaning of my sentence.